# Solving "12 balls and a scale" puzzle programmatically

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

There is a famous [12 balls and a scale](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/183/twelve-balls-and-a-scale) puzzle. This [answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/224/10659) (which is great by the way) explains how to get the weighting schedule to solve the puzzle. This weighting schedule is built "with trial and error".

I am wondering how to build that schedule *programmatically*. What would you suggest ?

Comment: There seem to be some discussions about this on the network: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/284/n-balls-and-a-scale https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15423/optimal-algorithm-for-finding-the-odd-spheres/336224#336224

Comment: various approaches to identification.  maybe interesting?  http://gurmeet.net/puzzles/twelve-coins/index.html